# Can anyone recommend some linux kernel related books for beginners?

Tags: linux-kernel, books

I want to know the mechanism of Linux kernel. But I was confused by such a huge number of concepts, structs and functions after the reading of *Understanding the Linux kernel*. This book details too many concepts which make me lost in the complex net of relationships between these components.

I think I want a book which has many figures to describe these relationships behind this monolithic system. This book needs to describe the mechanisms of kernel instead of details how these functions work.

Is there a such book?

Comment: Shopping questions are OT here, sorry.

Comment: It seems that my question is not suitable here. According to Kasra's answer the __Linux Kernel Development__ is much easier than __Understanding The Linux Kernel__ for beginners. I really hope my question will help people who have the same problem. Please leave a comment if you have a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Linux Kernel Development**
   Third Edition by Robert Love is a good book !
2. **Linux From Scratch**
   Version 7.4
   Created by Gerard Beekmans
   Edited by Matthew Burgess and Bruce Dubbs,
   This package provides an arbitrary precision numeric processing language. It satisfies a requirement needed
   when building the Linux kernel. and contains programs needed to administer Linux kernel modules. and etc..
3. **O'Reilly's Understanding The Linux Kernel.**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit as if you were looking for a general book on kernel development rather than Linux specifically. If that is the case check what books are recommended by appropriate courses (OS/Kernel development) on a nearby university and see which will be written in a manner that suits you. Also check what MIT or other similar universities have to say about that.